# array retain question

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, retain

im fairly new to objective-c, most of it is clear however when it comes to memory managment I fall a little short. Currently what my application does is during a NSURLConnection when the method `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` is called upon I enter a method to parse some data, put it into an array, and return that array. However I'm not sure if this is the best way to do so since I don't release the array from memory within the custom method (method1, see the attached code)

Below is a small script to better show what im doing

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface memoryRetainTestViewController : UIViewController {

    NSArray *mainArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *mainArray;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "memoryRetainTestViewController.h"

@implementation memoryRetainTestViewController
@synthesize mainArray;


// this would be the parsing method
-(NSArray*)method1
{
    // ???: by not release this, is that bad. Or does it get released with mainArray
    NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple",@"orange", @"grapes", "peach", nil];

    return newArray;
}


// this method is actually
// -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
-(void)method2
{
    mainArray = [self method1];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    mainArray = nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [mainArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: by the way if you just have __[[NSArray alloc] init]__ the item is not retained neither autoreleased. So it won't be leaked memory, it will just be released at some time out of the scope of the function. While if use __[NSArray array withObjects:..]__ it will be easily autoreleased and you won't need to release it on dealloc.

Comment: @Jack: That's nonsense, you own the objects created through `-alloc`. Also, assigning autoreleased objects to ivars is bad, they will be released when the current autorelease pool is drained, not when the life-time of your object ends. You definitely have some things mixed up about manual ref-counting and auto-release, i recommend reading the Memory Management Guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `-method1` first creates a new array and then overwrites it with a new one:

```
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // first array, retained
newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];  // second array, auto-released, 
                                            // pointer to first one lost
```

The first array is simply leaked here. You are also leaking the array stored in the ivar, just use the synthesized setter to avoid that - it retains and releases for you.

If you haven't done so yet, read the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for Cocoa.

A better version:

```
- (NSArray *)method1 {
    NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];    
    return newArray;
}

- (void)method2 {
    self.mainArray = [self method1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, explained this well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your `newArray` is released when `mainArray` is released. But this just if `method2` is called once.

We're talking about references so if you have

```
newArray = something
mainArray = newArray
[mainArray release]
```

both variables will be referencing to just a `NSArray*`. Then in your case `newArray` is just a local so there's no problem.

The problem occurs if you call `method2` twice:

```
newArray = something
mainArray = newArray
newArray = something2
mainArray = newArray <- old reference is lost
[mainArray release] <- just something2 is released
```

To avoid this issue you should make sure to release `mainArray` before overwriting the reference with another object.

EDIT: didn't noticed that you were creating the array twice :) No, that's not good..

Comment: Ya... some of this is coming back to addressing and pointers back in my c++ class last term heh. Thanks for the advice and help.